# Usage of Select with Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, select, repository-pattern

I created generic repository pattern for repository actions. I want to use Select for instance of repositories. My codes at below are explanatory for this situation;

This is my **IGenericRepository**;

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class 
{
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(Guid id);
    
    /*.(like that methods...)*/

    Task<T> Select(); //Which code should be here?
}
```

This is my **GenericRepository** class;

```
  public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
  {
    private readonly Context _context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbContext = context.Set<T>();
    }
    
    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.FindAsync(id);
    }
        
    /*.(like that methods...)*/

    public Task<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) //What should be parameter?
    {
        return _dbContext.Select() // which code should be here? 
    }
```

This is my **service class**;

```
public class ProfileService :IProfileService
{
    private readonly IProfileRepository _profileRepository;

    public ProfileService(IProfileRepository profileRepository)
    {
        _profileRepository = profileRepository;
    }

    public Task<ProfileUpdateResponseModel> UpdateProfile(ProfileUpdateRequestModel updateRequestModel)
    {
        var profile =_profileRepository.AsQueryable()
            .Include(p => p.User)
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.User.Id == Guid.Parse(updateRequestModel.UserId))
            .Select()  // I can't use Select in there.. What I should?
        
    }
}
```

How I can handle it? I have to use select method without repository pattern? Or Is my taking instance of Context wrong?

Comment: why are you reinventing around linq for the repository pattern? just allow `IQueryable` to flow.

Comment: Also I need to some information of select. Yes, actually Select is combination of where()+ToList() . But I use select for modifing. So, Is this code usable for me; 


public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }

Comment: _"I have to use select method without repository pattern?"_ EF already _is_ a generic repository.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry I can not got it

Comment: He is basically saying the same thing as me: throw away that code and just use entity framework as it is intended. It can already do what you want. You just deprived yourself of the functionality by creating your own wrapper.

Comment: Please do not call a method that filters `Select` in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the GenericRepository pattern is used when you want to minimize redundant code for managing database queries for domain objects. So, in general, it contains some methods such as `GetById`, `Delete`, `Update`, `Create` and other methods common to your repositories.

There is a link on [example of GenericRepository + UoF implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

As far as I understand, your `Select()` method should return some data for a given predicate, so it might look like this:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? predicate = null,
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> dbQuery = _dbSet.AsNoTracking();

        if (predicate != null)
        {
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(predicate);
        }

        return navigationProperties.Aggregate(
            dbQuery,
            (current, navigationProperty) => current.Include(navigationProperty));
    }
```

One of the downsides is returning `IQueryable<TEntity>`: some developers would say it's not a good practice, but that's up to you. I leave a link to the discussion of this topic [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/192044/should-repositories-return-iqueryable).

If you need a method that returns `Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>>`, just make the `GetQuery()` method private and use it like shown below:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? predicate = null,
        CancellationToken token = default,
        params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        return await GetQuery(predicate, navigationProperties).ToListAsync(token);
    }
```